# Taylor series of $\sqrt{\ln\left(\frac{1}{x}\right)}$

Tags: taylor-expansion

I am trying to compute the Taylor series of:

$\sqrt{\ln\left(\frac{1}{x}\right)}$

I have computed the derivatives and evaluated them in $x=1/e$ but I cannot find the formula for the sequence of the coefficients.

Any other ideas?

Thanks!

PS: The approximation should be valid over the interval $x \in [0,1]$

Comment: As an aside, $~\displaystyle\int_0^1\sqrt{\ln\bigg(\frac{1}{x}\bigg)}~dx=\frac{\sqrt\pi}2$

Comment: The function $\sqrt{\ln(x)}$ has problem points at both $0$ and $1$. It follows that a Taylor approximation can only be valid over all of $(0,1)$ (let alone the boundary points) if it is centered at $1/2$ (or a complex number with real part $1/2$).

Comment: See also http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/820395/formula-for-sequence-of-integers

Answer (score 2):

This is a note on how you might compute the derivatives using implicit differentiation. It isn't really an answer, but was too long for a comment, and someone may see how to use this in an answer.

$$y=\left(-\ln(x)\right)^{\frac 12}$$

$$y'=\frac 12\left(-\ln(x)\right)^{-\frac 12}\cdot-\frac 1x=-\frac 1{2xy}$$

Whence $$2xyy'=-1$$ and $$2yy'+2xy'^2+2xyy''=0$$ From which you can cancel a factor two and keep going to compute higher derivatives.

Using $2xyy'=-1$ you can multiply through by $y'$ and obtain:

$$2yy'^2+2xy'^3-y''=0$$ or $$y''=2xy'^3+2yy'^2$$ Which you can differentiate as often as you like.

Comment: Maybe you can substitute in a power series (choice of center) and get a recurrence relation (depending on *all* previous terms) for the coefficients?

Answer (score 1):

Let's try to find the expansion about $x=1/2$.  Also, note that $\ln(1/x) = -\ln(x)$.
$$
f(x) = \sqrt{-\ln(x)};\quad f(1/2) = \sqrt{\ln(2)}\\
f'(x)= \frac{1}{2}(-\ln(x))^{-1/2}\cdot(-1/x); \quad f'(1/2) = -1/(\sqrt{\ln(2)})
$$
Whatever this Taylor Series is, it's only going to get worse from here.  To get something workable, I think you'll have to settle for something that converges only over a part of $(0,1)$.

Comment: This sounds like a good idea. I will try to evaluate in other points and look at the resulting coefficients of the Taylor series. Thanks.

Comment: It should be $f'(x)=\frac{1}{2}(-\ln(x))^{-\frac{1}{2}}(-1/x)$.

Comment: @user263326 feel free to fix it

Answer (score 0):

### Taylor's series of $\boldsymbol{\sqrt{\ln\frac{1}{x}}\,}$

It is clear that
\begin{equation*}
\sqrt{\ln\frac{1}{x}}\,=\sqrt{-\ln x}\,.
\end{equation*}
By virtue of the Faa di Bruno formula and several properties of the Bell polynomials of the second kind (or say, partial Bell polynomials) $\textrm{B}_{n,k}$ for $n\ge k\ge0$, we obtain
\begin{align*}
\bigl(\sqrt{-\ln x}\,\bigr)^{(n)}&=\sum_{k=0}^{n}\bigl(\sqrt{u}\,\bigr)^{(k)} \textrm{B}_{n,k}\Biggl(-\frac{0!}{x}, (-1)^2\frac{1!}{x^2}, \dotsc, (-1)^{n-k+1}\frac{(n-k)!}{x^{n-k+1}}\Biggr)\\
&=\sum_{k=0}^{n}\biggl\langle\frac{1}{2}\biggr\rangle_k u^{1/2-k} \frac{(-1)^n}{x^n} \textrm{B}_{n,k}(0!,1!, \dotsc, (n-k)!)\\
&=\frac{(-1)^n}{x^n} \sum_{k=0}^{n}\biggl\langle\frac{1}{2}\biggr\rangle_k (-\ln x)^{1/2-k} (-1)^{n-k}s(n,k)\\
&=-\frac{1}{x^n} \sum_{k=0}^{n}\frac{(2k-3)!!}{2^k} \frac{s(n,k)}{(-\ln x)^{k-1/2}}
\end{align*}
for $n\ge0$, where $u=u(x)=-\ln x$, the notation $\langle\alpha\rangle_k$ denotes the falling factorial, and the quantity $s(n,k)$ stands for the Stirling numbers of the first kind.
Consequently, for $x_0\in(0,1)$, we arrive at
\begin{equation*}
\boxed{\sqrt{\ln\frac{1}{x}}\,
=\sqrt{-\ln x}\,
=-\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\Biggl[\frac{1}{x_0^n} \sum_{k=0}^{n}\frac{(2k-3)!!}{2^k} \frac{s(n,k)}{(-\ln x_0)^{k-1/2}}\Biggr]\frac{(x-x_0)^n}{n!}, \quad |x-x_0|<\min\{x_0,1-x_0\}.}
\end{equation*}
In particular, since
\begin{equation*}
\lim_{x\to1/\textrm{e}}\bigl(\sqrt{-\ln x}\,\bigr)^{(n)}
=-\textrm{e}^n \sum_{k=0}^{n}\frac{(2k-3)!!}{2^k}s(n,k)
\end{equation*}
and
\begin{equation*}
\lim_{x\to1/2}\bigl(\sqrt{-\ln x}\,\bigr)^{(n)}
=-2^n \sum_{k=0}^{n}\frac{(2k-3)!!}{2^k}\frac{s(n,k)}{(\ln2)^{k-1/2}}
\end{equation*}
for $n\ge0$, we find
\begin{equation*}
\boxed{\sqrt{\ln\frac{1}{x}}\,
=\sqrt{-\ln x}\,
=-\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \Biggl[\sum_{k=0}^{n}\frac{(2k-3)!!}{2^k}s(n,k)\Biggr]\frac{\textrm{e}^n}{n!}\biggl(x-\frac1{\textrm{e}}\biggr)^n, \quad \biggl|x-\frac1{\textrm{e}}\biggr|<\frac{1}{\textrm{e}}}
\end{equation*}
and
\begin{equation*}
\boxed{\sqrt{\ln\frac{1}{x}}\,
=\sqrt{-\ln x}\,
=-\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \Biggl[\sum_{k=0}^{n}\frac{(2k-3)!!}{2^k} \frac{s(n,k)}{(\ln2)^{k-1/2}}\Biggr]\frac{2^n}{n!}\biggl(x-\frac12\biggr)^n, \quad \biggl|x-\frac12\biggr|<\frac{1}{2}.}
\end{equation*}

All concepts, definitions, notions, properties, and notations used above can be found in the references listed below, for example.

References

1. https://qifeng618.wordpress.com/2018/03/19/some-papers-on-explicit-formulas-of-special-values-for-the-bell-polynomials-of-the-second-kind/.
2. Feng Qi, Muhammet Cihat Dagli, and Dongkyu Lim, *Several explicit formulas for (degenerate) Narumi and Cauchy polynomials and numbers*, Open Mathematics **19** (2021), no. 1, 833--849; available online at https://doi.org/10.1515/math-2021-0079.
3. Feng Qi and Bai-Ni Guo, *Some properties of the Hermite polynomials*, Georgian Mathematical Journal **28** (2021), no. 6, 925--935; available online at https://doi.org/10.1515/gmj-2020-2088.
4. Feng Qi, Da-Wei Niu, Dongkyu Lim, and Bai-Ni Guo, *Closed formulas and identities for the Bell polynomials and falling factorials*, Contributions to Discrete Mathematics **15** (2020), no. 1, 163--174; available online at https://doi.org/10.11575/cdm.v15i1.68111.
5. Feng Qi, Da-Wei Niu, Dongkyu Lim, and Yong-Hong Yao, *Special values of the Bell polynomials of the second kind for some sequences and functions*, Journal of Mathematical Analysis and Applications **491** (2020), no. 2, Paper No. 124382, 31 pages; available online at https://doi.org/10.1016/j.jmaa.2020.124382.
6. Lan Wu, Xue-Yan Chen, Muhammet Cihat Dagli, and Feng Qi, *On degenerate array type polynomials*, Computer Modeling in Engineering & Sciences **131** (2022), no. 1, 295--305; available online at https://www.doi.org/10.32604/cmes.2022.018778.

Answer (score -1):

Hint: the general Taylor series expansion is

$$
\begin{align}
f(x) &= f(x_0) + {f'(x-x_0)(x-x_0)} + {f''(x_0) (x-x_0)^2\over 2!} + \cdots\\
&= \sum_{n=0}^\infty {{d^n\over dx^n}f(x)|_{x=x_0} \times (x-x_0)^n \over n!}
\end{align}
$$

This works wherever all the derivatives exist at $x_0$ and the function is continuous between $x$ and $x_0$.

For this specific problem:

$$
f(x) = f({1\over e}) + f'({1\over e})(x-{1\over e}) + {f''({1\over e})(x-{1\over e})^2\over 2} + {f'''({1\over e})(x-{1\over e})^3\over 3!} + \cdots
$$

Comment: I know how to compute a Taylor series. The problem in this case is that I cannot find the formula for the coefficients that result from evaluating the derivatives in any $x_0$

Comment: I'm afraid this is not what the OP is looking for

Comment: I don't understand.  In the post you said "I have computed the derivatives and evaluated them in $x=1/e$".  The sequence of coefficients would be $f(1/e)$, $f'(1/e)$, $f''(1/e)/2$, etc.